# Postfix doesn't accept pipe

Tags: postfix, email-server, email-bounces, aliases

I've tried to configure postfix to execute the script /tmp/test.sh each time the user "bounce" receives a mail. My /etc/postfix/aliases:

```
...
bounce: "| /tmp/test.sh"
...
```

If I send an mail to that user, I get back:

```
<"| /tmp/test.sh"@mydomain>: user unknown
```

What have I missed, or what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Even after removing the quotes: Same error... Script is executable and interpreter is set in first line

Comment: did you try removing the space between the pipe symbol and your command?

Answer (score 1):

do not use " (quotation marks) , because it will treat everything in between as address instead of pipe. 
make sure your script is executeable.